# SQL select single distinct values from multiple columns (not combined values)

Tags: sql

For example, I have the following table:

```
UserId Department1 Department2
------------------------------
1      Sales       Marketing
2      Research
3      Sales
```

And I want to get the following Results

```
DistinctDepartments
-------------------
Sales
Marketing
Research
```

I found lots of solutions that show me the distinct combined values of multiple columns, but I need the overall distinct values, as if all values would be in the same column.

Thankyou

Chris

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try to use `union` with both columns

```
select Department1 
from tab
union 
select Department2 
from tab
```

NOTE: `union` command eliminates duplicates

Comment: Thank you, that was exactly what I was looking for - and learned that union eliminates duplicates.

Comment: @ElChupanibre Don't problem, but remember ;)

Answer (score 4):

Using `union` is definitely a reasonable approach to this problem.  In most databases, though, the following may be faster:

```
select distinct (case when n = 1 then Department1 else Department2 end)
from tab cross join
     (select 1 as n union all select 2) n
```

The reason is that the table is only scanned once, rather than once for each column.  This can be particularly important when `tab` is not really a table, but a more expensive view.  (And some databases support `unpivot` which behaves similarly to this.)